# Why does evaluating an expression in system.time() make variables available in global environment?

Tags: r, scope

Can somebody please explain what happens when an expression is evaluated in `system.time`?  In particular, why are any variables that are declared in the `expr` argument visible in the global environment?

Here is a pared-down version of the innards of `system.time` that does nothing other than evaluating the expression that is passed to the function:

```
st <- function(expr){
  expr
}

st(aa <- 1)
aa
[1] 1
```

Clearly the effect of this is that it creates the variable `aa` in the global environment.  This baffles me, since I thought that assigning a variable inside a function makes it local in scope.

What happens here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is because **supplied arguments** are evaluated in the evaluation frame of the calling function (as described in [Section 4.3.3](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Argument-evaluation) of the R Language Definition document).

The expression wrapped by the user in `system.time()` is a supplied argument which gets matched positionally to `expr`. Then, when `expr`'s evaluation is forced in the body of `system.time`, it is evaluated in the evaluation frame of the calling function. If `system.time()` was called from the `.GlobalEnv`, that is where any assignments that are a part of `expr` will take place.

**EDIT:**

Here's an example showing that `expr` is evaluated in the global environment if it is a **supplied** (but not a **default**) argument.

```
st2 <- function(expr = newVar <- 33){
   expr
}

# Using the default argument -- eval and assignment 
# within evaluation frame of the function. 
st2()
newVar
Error: object 'newVar' not found

# Using a supplied argument -- eval and assignment
# within the calling function's evaluation frame (here .GlobalEnv)
st2(newVar <- 44)
newVar
# [1] 44
```

Comment: I can take your word for this, but will award bonus points if you can find a reference in the R manuals. :-)

Comment: Err, your answer (+1) seems a lot more explicit to my intuition :)

Comment: @Andrie -- I meant to thank you for the interesting question.  Does my super-faint link to the R Language definition count as a reference to the R manuals? ;)

Comment: +1 Your link to the manuals is not faint at all and very helpful.  Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

EDIT : as per @Tommy's comment: The evaluation actually only takes place once the argument expr is used (that's the lazy evaluation).

What is passed is a language object, not an expression. You basically nest the `<-` function (with two arguments) within the st() function call, and the **result** of the `<-` call is passed to to st. As you can see in `?assignOps`, the `<-` function returns the assigned value silently. As @Josh told you already, this evaluation of the nested function takes place in the environment the function is called from.

What you do, is equivalent to

```
st(mean(1:10))
```

To see the difference, you can do:

```
st <- function(expr){
  typeof(expr)
}
> st(aa <- 1)
[1] "double"
> st(expression(aa <- 1))
[1] "expression"
```

For the structure of the call, you can do:

```
st <- function(expr){
  str(as.list(match.call()))
}
> st(mean(1:10))
List of 2
 $     : symbol st
 $ expr: language mean(1:10)
> st(aa <- 1)
List of 2
 $     : symbol st
 $ expr: language aa <- 1
```

Comment: It's incorrect to say that `aa <- 1` is evaluated before calling `st`. It is only evaluated when it is USED in the `st` function. Try `st <- function(expr) NULL` and then `st(stop('foo'))`. The stop expression isn't USED in `st`, so the call never fails...

Comment: ...also note that `typeof(expr)` evaluates `expr` in order to check its type.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the `expr` is evaluated *before* handling that to the function. POC example:

```
> st <- function(expr){
+   eval(parse(text=expr))
+ }
> 
> st('aa <- 1')
> aa
Error: object 'aa' not found
```

So I think the function gets `expr` as only `aa`. Another example:

```
> st <- function(expr){
+   str(expr)
+ }
> 
> st(aa <- 1)
 num 1
```

I might be wrong, it is rather an intuition :) But thanks, that is a good puzzle!

---

**Update:**

```
> system.time(a <- 1)
   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       0 
> a
[1] 1
> rm(a)
> fn <- function() a <- 1
> system.time(fn())
   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       0 
> a
Error: object 'a' not found
```

Comment: In the source code for `system.time` you'll notice that `expr` only gets evaluated after several housekeeping activities are performed (e.g. starting the clock).  Your modified function takes a string as input, not a bit of code (as does `system.time`).

Comment: @Andrie: that is right that `expr` can be found later in `system.time`, but this does not affect the base idea of my answer. See updated examples.